# How to know submodules in a branch without checking it out

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there any programmatic way of finding out what submodules there are in a non-cheched-out commit?  Basically, I would like to be able to do a `git submodule status <commit>` (sadly that option does not exist, at least in 1.9.7.5)

I can think of two alternatives; none of them seems elegant enough:

1. `git submodule summary -n 1 commit`; then parse output and deduce the differences in submodules with `git submodule status`
2. Get the content of the file ".gitmodules" at that specific commit, and then parse it

Any simpler solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
git ls-tree -r <commit> | awk '$2 == "commit"'
```

Although that only tells you the path to where the submodule is attached and the corresponding commit that should be checked out there. If you want to get the URL or other information, you'll probably have to parse the `.gitmodules` file from that commit, as you mentioned.

Comment: Nice.  I will add the '-d' option to ls-tree to save some work to `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

could you use a second index with GIT_INDEX_FILE and then run `git submodule status --cached`?

I don't use submodules so not 100% sure the syntax will work

```
git read-tree --index-output=$tmp_index $branch
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$tmp_index git submodule status --cached
```

Comment: How would I generate that index?  My index file is about 2Mbs in size; I worry about performance if I need to check submodule state in many commits.

Comment: Tried that solution.  With the index trick, the `git submodule status` commmand detects the submodule paths for the commit correctly (as it start to print them), but unfortunately then the command fails when trying to find those paths in the checked out file ".gitmodules".