# How to get name list for chaned files in specific git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

A parent git repo contains several submodules, and the folder structure as belowing:

```
parent-dir
    src
    module-a
    module-b
    module-c
    module-spec
```

In one parent git commit, a submodule may have multi commits.
How to get all file names that changed in `module-spec` contains in a parent commit?

[Found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757091/git-list-of-all-changed-files-including-those-in-submodules) but the answer do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`git ls-tree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26262153/7976758) to get commits of the submodule registered in the superproject and run `git diff` directly in the submodule:

```
prev_commit=`git ls-tree HEAD~ module-spec | awk '{print $3}'`
curr_commit=`git ls-tree HEAD  module-spec | awk '{print $3}'`
cd module-spec
git diff --name-only $prev_commit $curr_commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git diff --submodule[=diff/log/short] HEAD~ -- module-spec
```

`git diff --submodule` to run diff on submodules. `[=diff/log/short]` — choose one of the formats; default is `short`.

`HEAD~` to run diff between the previous commit of the superproject and the current.

`module-spec` to limit the diff only for the submodule. Excludes diff for the very superproject and other submodules.

Comment: Tried `diff/log/short` but neither one can't get the file list. But your another answer works!