# How to show a diff with --name-only for all (including nested) submodules?

Tags: git, diff, git-submodules

I know how to make a diff with submodules

```
git diff "$@"
```

However this diff shows only file content for super-project and not for submodules. It displays the new sha1 of each new commited submodule but not their file content.

I know how to make a diff with more details

```
git diff --submodule=diff  "$@"
```

However this diff show all file content for both the super project and its submodules

How could I do this but with the --name-only style?

```
git diff --name-only "$@"
```

and

```
git diff --name-only --submodule=diff  "$@"
```

give the same results

---

Note: an obvious reason for my command not to be working is the lack of implementation. however, there migth be some trick with git submodule foreach but this appears not to be straigth forward

Note: it shall be recursive (i.e. compare as well submodule's submodules), if your solution includes 'git submodule foreach' then it will be 'git submodule --recursive foreach'. This is the most important part of the question because it's not hard to make a git submodule foreach, but a git submodule --recursive foreach gives me headaches

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I believe `git submodule foreach git diff --name-only` is the only solution.

Comment: yes, but git submodule foreach git diff --name-only won't do the wanted job. it will only make the diff for the SP and each SM, between current sha1 and previous... if the new SP sha1 points to a SM with 2 new commits, it does not work

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67602473/7976758) in a `git submodule foreach` loop?

Comment: that is quite hardcore

Comment: Just in case you're unaware, if you get this working, you can save it as a git alias so that you don't ever have to write it out in full again

Comment: @GuillaumeD "*that is quite hardcore*" I don't see any other way.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/sh
# See the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/67724347/7976758

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage $0 from_commit [to_commit]"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$prog_dir" -o -z "$prog_name" ]; then
    start_dir="`pwd`"
    prog_dir="`dirname \"$0\"`"
    prog_name="`basename \"$0\"`"
    cd "$prog_dir"
    # Get full path
    prog_dir="`pwd`"
    cd "$start_dir"
    export prog_dir prog_name
fi

from_commit="$1"
to_commit="${2:-HEAD}"
export from_commit to_commit

# In the superproject
git --no-pager diff --name-only "$from_commit" "$to_commit"

git submodule foreach '
    # In submodule "$name"
    prev_commit=`(git -C "$toplevel" ls-tree "$from_commit" "$sm_path" | awk "{print \\$3}")`
    curr_commit=`(git -C "$toplevel" ls-tree "$to_commit" "$sm_path" | awk "{print \\$3}")`
    "$prog_dir/$prog_name" $prev_commit $curr_commit
'
```

Comment: You can export variables your invoked command will need, and instead of ls-tree|awk, just do rev-parse, so you can put it all in singlequotes. ``…foreach 'git diff --name-only `git -C $toplevel rev-parse $from_commit:$sm_path $to_commit:$sm_path`'``. should be much more readable.

Comment: the issue is that it is not recursive, if you have a nested modification inside a submodule's submodule it won't work

Comment: @GuillaumeD Alas, you're right. Making the script recursive possible; it requires to store `from_commit`/`to_commit` from the previous level.

Comment: @GuillaumeD Please, see the current version. It's recursive. I debugged it on a deeply recursive repository, I have a few at the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
recursivenameonlysubmodulediff() { 
git update-ref refs/scratch/old $1
git update-ref refs/scratch/new $2
git diff --name-only scratch/old scratch/new
export realtop=$PWD
git submodule foreach -q --recursive '
        git update-ref refs/scratch/old `git -C .. rev-parse scratch/old:$sm_path`
        git update-ref refs/scratch/new `git -C .. rev-parse scratch/new:$sm_path`
        prefix=$toplevel/$sm_path/
        git diff --name-only scratch/old scratch/new | sed s,^,${prefix#$realtop/},
'
}
```

will handle the russian-dolls-submodules case, using the `scratch` refs to avoid them getting inadvertently pushed or fetched.