# list commit hashes for submodules recursively between to commits in the super repo

Tags: git

I have a super-repo structure like this (for example):

```
A --+--> B --> D
    |
    +--> C --+--> E
             |
             +--> F
```

Though in reality it's much bigger and deeper.

Ultimately I am trying get a list of all merges that occured between two versions at the top level. So in repo `A` I can do a `git log` between two dates - showing just the merges to branch `development`:

```sh
git log --merges --first-parent development --oneline --since="1 month ago" --until="today"
36bd8f6 (HEAD -> development) Merge branch 'feature-184' into 'development'
9e09290 Merge branch 'feature-173' into 'development'
b287736 Merge branch 'feature-268' into 'development'
a33099f Merge branch 'feature-262' into 'development'
186dbbe Merge branch 'feature-261' into 'development'
a32269a Merge branch 'feature-266' into 'development'
```

I can do this for any repo by data or by pair of hashes, so `git log --merges --first-parent development --oneline a32269a..36bd8f6` would give the same result

So now lets say I have selected the two hashes from repo A `a32269a -> 36bd8f6`. What I want to do now is get the commit hashes for each of the repos below that match the two hashes at repo A.

For example when I checkout A at `36bd8f6` (development), and do a submodule update recursive, then repo F might be at git hash `aaaaaaa2`. Then when I checkout A at `a32269a` (~1 month ago), and submodule update, then repo F might be at hash `aaaaaaa1`.

So I want to find these pair of hashes for each repo. I can do this by checking out repo A at the two commits I am interested in (plus update the submodules)... but this is slow and means checking out different versions and updating subdmoules etc.. so I have to make sure my submodules are all in a clean state etc... This is all doable, but not so convenient.

Is there a way I can query git to ask it. "What is submodule F's git commit hash when submodule A is at commit hash "xxxxxxx"?

Comment: Could https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727152/7976758 help?

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you need is to checkout each commit in A, then run `git submodule status`, which will tell you the sha1 each submodule should be at. But LeGEC's answer is much more helpful, so nevermind.

Comment: @joanis : I looked at the doc for `git submodule status`, but couldn't find a way to say "I want to get the status at *that other commit* (not HEAD)". Perhaps you know of a way to specifiy that ?

Comment: @LeGEC, I just read the manual again, and I expect this won't work well recursively. And no, it doesn't accept a sha1, you have to checkout that sha1 first and then run it. So meh as an answer for this question.

Comment: @phd thanks for that - I think the main issue is recusing down the submodules, submodules one level deep is much easier (unless I mis-understood your code)

Comment: @joanis as you say - recursively getting the hashs is the trick! - i'll see what LeGEC's answer suggests, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the hash of a direct submodule, you can use :

```
git rev-parse [commit]:[path/to/submodule]

# for example :
$ git rev-parse a32269a:B
eacf32a     # complete hash of the commit for 'B' in a32269a
$ git rev-parse a32269a:C
eacf33b
```

I wasn't able to make this command work to get nested submodules straight from repo `A`
(e.g : `git rev-parse a32269a:C/F` doesn't work),
you can however :

- cd into `C` to get info from that repo :

```
$ cd C
$ git rev-parse eacf33b:F
```

- or use `--git-dir` to scan the repository information of C submodule :

```
# the repo information for submodule C is stored under '.git/modules/' :
$ git --git-dir .git/modules/C rev-parse eacf33b:F
```

---

`git ls-tree` will also output the commit hash of a submodule at a given revision :

```
# if submodule is at "top level" of your repo :
$ git ls-tree <commit>
# if submodule is in 'parent/dir/'
$ git ls-tree <commit>:parent/dir

# sample output :
100644 blob f0d8b44a89c2516a73f330c15219569b84198fd4    .gitmodules
100644 blob 72943a16fb2c8f38f9dde202b7a70ccc19c52f34    a.txt
040000 tree a82b9a1f72f28fb99c34af337bac5326db0822ed    dir
160000 commit 60163ec080c11fb75294846faf146af23e616627  mymodule  # <- submodule
```

As with `git rev-parse`, you will need to `cd` into the submodule or explicitly provide the `--git-dir` of the submodule to dive into nested submodules.

Comment: hmm.. I'll have to tinker with this tomorrow. But from what I understand you can use rev-parse to query the submodule commit-hashs for any parent level commit-hash - and so "walking" the folder structure should be fairly simple - but will need a script. Not sure I can do it in pure git (like with foreach submodule). But this could work, I will have to report back on this...

Comment: @code_fodder: yes - the generally hard part of the problem is that if superproject *P* at commit *Pc1* has submodule *S1*, and *S1* is at commit *C1* which has submodule *S2*, that does not mean that *P* at *Pc2* is still using *S1*-at-*C1*, it may be using *S1*-at-*C2* and that might not have submodule *S2* at all, or it might be under a different path, etc. So you need to search the entirety of commit *C2* in *S1* (with `git ls-tree -r`) to look for gitlinks (entities with mode `160000`), which refer to commits in other Git repositories.