List all files modified since the last commit to the root repo including submodules
To illustrate the problem, let's say we have the following repository structure.
MainRepo
  file1
  file2
  directory1
    file3
  submodule1
    fileA
    fileB
  submodule2
    submodule3

file* are tracked by the MainRepo. submodule1 and submodule2 are submodules of MainRepo. submodule3 is a submodule of submodule2.
The main repo and the submodules have their own commits. Certain commits of submodule1 and submodule2 correspond to the current commit of MainRepo. But the currently checked out commits of these submodules may not be the same as the commits committed with the MainRepo commit.
What I want to do is get a list of all the files, with paths relative to MainRepo, that are not in the same state as in the current MainRepo commit. And I want this to go recursively into submodules, comparing the state of the files there to the state in the submodule commit corresponding to the MainRepo commit.
By "not in the same state" I mean modified, deleted, or new files i.e. untracked (unless they are ignored).
To illustrate what I want, let's say the main repo is on commit aaabbb. This commit points to commit aaa111 of submodule1. But currently, submodule1 is on commit aaa122. This commit aaa122 modified fileA. There have been no untracked changes to fileA since then. After this commit, fileB has been modified and the changes have not been committed. file1 and file3 have been edited, too.
What I would like to see in this case is:
MainRepo/file1
MainRepo/directory1/file3
MainRepo/submodule1/fileA
MainRepo/submodule1/fileB

Simply put, the list should contain paths to all files that are not the same as what you'd get from git clone --recurse-submodules MainRepo.
git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2 or git ls-files -om --exclude-standard don't do what I want, because they don't go into the submodules. And I need to go into submodules of submodules.

Please see if the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727152/7976758 works for you.

Check the options suggested here (Julia Evans' blog): https://jvns.ca/blog/2024/02/16/popular-git-config-options/#submodule-stuff

or https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100667/86072
